# Cannot wrap ASP.NET MVC table in DataTables grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

Vow for help from SOers,

I currently create an ASP.NET MVC project, and lose my temper with wrapping the table in jQuery DataTables. For testing purposes I run standard MVC template with my DB attached (DB First approach). It successfully populates the table with data, but it does not provide jQuery DataTables fuctionality (even the basic one). The data from the other DB table, (WeaponTypeDescr column in WeaponTypes), is successfully uploaded in the table too. Both controller and view are created via scaffolding option for ItemType model, the table is supposed to run in Index page. 
So here's the code of ItemTypes/Index:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.ItemType>

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }

@section styles {
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" />
}

        @section scripts {
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#ItemTypeTable').DataTable(

                    );
                });
            </script>

        }

        <h2>Index</h2>

        <p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
        </p>


            <table id="ItemTypeTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemType1)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WeaponType.WeaponTypeDescr)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemType1)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WeaponType.WeaponTypeDescr)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ItemTypeID }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ItemTypeID }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ItemTypeID })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
```

Here's my _Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("WeaponTypes", "Index", "WeaponTypes")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I suppose it has nothing to do with the problem, but just for the "chain of custody" -- BundleConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));


            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

So, the question is: What am I missing? I've looked through several manuals (definitely [this one](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html), also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u147Q0NY6Qg)), performed just according to the examples (with minor deviations), but still nothing happens, the picture is 
[quite the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyB4p.png). 
PS: Do not worry, the content of the database is in Russian, it's OK, trust me in case you do not understand what's written :).

***EDIT***

In order to overcome [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): I'm looking for the way to present data in datatable and:
- print the table;
- create PDF file;
- drop it into Excel (.xlsx preferred).

The best solution I see is DataTables, which, regretfully, still does not work in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your datatables to work you have to do two things.

1. add a css

   ```
   @section scripts {
       <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
       @*!!!I included a css for datatables*@
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('#ItemTypeTable').DataTable(

               );
           });
       </script>
   }
   ```
2. Add a thead tag

   ```
   <table id="ItemTypeTable">
       @*!!!NEED THE thead*@
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ItemType1)
               </th>
               <th>
                   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WeaponType.WeaponTypeDescr)
               </th>
               <th></th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
   ```

Comment: The JQuery version I used worked 1.12.4.  You can use the same one as me, if you are not seeing the datatable formatting.

Comment: @kbau, thanks a lot! Did not suppose that these two simple actions make the result. To others, who face the problem: standard scaffolding DOES NOT add <thead> section, so be aware!